# Multi docker container NGINX+FLASK: missing app upstream defined through localhost

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask

EDIT: I checked and it seems that azure provides a default network bridge, for which then the localhost solution works fine.

I run a two container docker-compose NGINX + Gunicorn&Flask, and I want to set NGINX as reverse proxy for the application. I am trying to make it run on the AZURE cloud as CLI, but my Nginx is not able to find the upstream coming from the application. On my local machine I obtain this specifing in the nginx configuration the container name and the corrispective exposed port, which on the cloud seems not to be working.

I tried to change the proxy_pass to localhost (same port), but in this case it does not work even on my local machine, returning a 502 Bad Gateway error. I can anyway send requests to the application through the browser or any other method.
Nginx runs with supervisord.
Gunicorn run with 1 worker (gthread) with 4 different threads.

here my nginx.conf (the one which gets included):

```
server {    
    listen 80;

    location / {        
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://mycontainer:5000;
        # proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

and here the main one:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /app/logs/nginx_error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent"' ;

    access_log /app/logs/nginx_access.log main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
daemon off;
```

Answer (score 0):

If both, the nginx and the app, run containerized, then..

For your containers (or services) to find each other they must belong to the same network. So you need to call

```
docker network create -d DRIVER_NAME YOUR_NETWORK_NAME
```

Depending on what are you doing (standalone containers or swarm services) you have to choose between the **bridge** or the **overlay** [network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) when creating your network.

Then you execute **docker run** or **docker service create** using the **--network** flag and passing the name of your network.

Also the nginx config should contain something like the following

```
    server {
  listen 80;                      # host port - used by proxy
  server_name localhost;
  resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s ipv6=off;     # 127.0.0.11 the static IP address of the internal DNS server of the swarm
  set $upstream YOUR_SERVICE_NAME;            # mandatory when not using the upstream section              
  client_max_body_size 0;                     # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://$upstream:YOUR_SERVICE_PORT;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    #proxy_redirect     off;          # do not re-write the Location and Refresh header fields of an upstream server
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;          # required for docker
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;               
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it does not apply to my case. The main problem is that I do not have access to the docker commands on the azure cloud deployment system, i.e. I can not create a docker service on there. Then I really think it is something in the local definition of NGINX of localhost.